# Discrepancy between Eclipse compiler and javac - Enums, interfaces, and generics

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, enumset

The following code compiles (and runs tests as expected) in Eclipse:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
public class EnumTest {

    static enum Cloneables implements Cloneable {
        One, Two, Three;
    }

    public <T extends Cloneable> T getOne(Class enumType) {
        EnumSet<? extends T> set = EnumSet.allOf(enumType);
        return set.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

However, compiling with either `javac` (JDK 7) directly or via Maven fails with the following error:

```
type argument ? extends T is not within bounds of type-variable E
```

To be honest, the complexity of enums + interfaces + type-parameters (generics) all at play at once threw me off as I was writing the code, but I thought I had finally gotten it right.

The goal is to write calling code like this:

```
Cloneable something = enumTest.getOne(Cloneables.class);
```

For example, in Eclipse the following test compiles and passes:

```
@Test
public void testGetFirst() {
    assertSame(Cloneables.One, getOne(Cloneables.class));
}
```

Any clues about which is "correct," Eclipse or javac, are appreciated.

Also appreciated is any advice about alternate ways to implement the idea: take a class as a method param that can be used in `EnumSet.allOf()` and that also determines the type of Enum objects in the `EnumSet`

*By the way, don't bother critiquing the purpose of this method; I've reduced it down from more useful/meaningful code. I'm not interested in discussing the merits of "finding the first element from an enum type" - that's not the point of this question.*

Comment: It appears that this may be a bug in javac (JDK 1.7.0_60). The accepted answer below is a work-around (and actually cleaner code). See the detailed analysis at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456459#c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `T` is an enum type, or it won't meet the constraints for `EnumSet`:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & Cloneable> T getOne(Class enumType)
```

Also, you don't need the wildcard in your `EnumSet`, and you shouldn't use the raw `Class` type:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & Cloneable> T getOne(Class<T> enumType) {
    EnumSet<T> set = EnumSet.allOf(enumType);
    return set.iterator().next();
}
```

Comment: I never even knew you could apply the `&` operator when declaring a type parameter like that. Even after almost 18 years writing Java code, I learned something new today!

Comment: By the way, the reason I used the raw form of `Class` is that without `T` extending `Enum` the Eclipse compiler wouldn't accept any value for the `Class` type parameter. So using it raw was a side-effect of not knowing to combine `Cloneable` and `Enum` for `T`.

Comment: Interestingly, Eclipse won't let me declare the set as `EnumSet<T>` - it complains that *"Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum<E>> of the type EnumSet<E>"*. Luckily, `EnumSet<? extends T?` works and is equivalent.

Comment: @E-Riz: No; actually, the bound should be `T extends Enum<T> & Cloneable`.  You can then remove the wildcard again.

Comment: @E-Riz Given that generics were added to Java in 2004, you've only had 10 years (almost 11) to learn about them :-). I find generics to be the most complex area of Java by far. Using them is not so bad, but when it comes to declaring any generic methods/classes, it can be quite formidable.